# problem with [] operator when using a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, operator-keyword, copy-constructor

I'm trying to make a copy constructor for Game. throughout the copy constructor I have to copy the elements of  one game into another. However when I try to  access the inner elemnts of the game I want to copy I get an error saying :

```
no operator "[]" matches these operands -- operand types are: mtm::Game [ std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::conditional_t<true, std::_Simple_types<std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>>>, std::_Vec_iter_types<std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>>, size_t, ptrdiff_t, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>> *, const std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>> *, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>> &, const std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>> &>>>> ]C/C++(349)
```

I'd appreciate any help with explaining why the [] operator doesn't work, here's the piece of code I wrote :

```
Game::Game(const Game& other)
{
    Game game(other.height, other.width);

    for (vector<vector<char>>::const_iterator row = other.game.begin(); row != 
                                                              other.game.end(); row++)
    {
        for(vector<char>::const_iterator col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++)
        {                
            game[row][col] = other[row][col];  ///////???
        }
    }
```

In addition to that, I'd like to ask if it's better to allocate a game using "new" or just declare it like I did in my code segment above.

Comment: First you can remove the whole copy constructor, because the default copy constructor is already working, if there arent more varables.

Comment: And iterator are nothing you can use an an indice of a vector, and iterator is more like a pointer to an element, so you only need to derefernce the row variable to get the row.

Comment: @Lala5th I tried using at but it didn't work as well

Comment: @gerum do you mean that I should do *row ? and there are more variables I just didn't include them in the code segment

Comment: vector<T> has a copy ctor - but anyway I would recomment to use range based for loops.
To copy the data manually (because you may need to modify it) you can write: https://godbolt.org/z/Kn6f1hc15

Comment: Does anyone know if it's better to allocate memory with "new" or just declare a game like I did above if I don't want the two games to be "related" to each other meaning that I don't the values of one to change if change the values of the other

Comment: It depends very much on the size of your game objects. Stack/register allocation is very fast and simple but also limited in size and fixed to the current stack frame. From the name "Game" I would assume it is a longer living object which could or should be allocated in heap storage.

Comment: @Saleh Your copy-ctor doesn't have _any_ effect. Just delete it, the default one will be enough.  You are attempting to copy data from `other` to a _local_ variable `game`. After the copy-ctor exits this local variable will cease to exist and the current instance will remain uninitialized. (unless you do something with `game` that you didn't show here)

Comment: @Lala5th -- `vector::operator[]` has **two** overloads; one is `const`-qualified, and the other isn't. `const vector<int> v(2, 1); std::cout << v[0];` is legal and works just fine.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thnaks! Didn't check because I know that for `std::map` there isn't a const qualified overload. That's weird that `std::vector` has but `std::map` does not

Comment: @Lala5th -- different isn't the same. `std::map::operator[]` is, essentially, a search function; if the search fails, it creates a new element. A `const`-qualified version couldn't do that, so would have to do something rather different (throw an exception?), which is too big an inconsistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[]` [operator of a vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) expects a `size_t` argument. You are passing an iterator which is why it doesn't compile.

`other[row][col]` can be replaced with just `*col`. `game[row][col]` is a little more tricky, you can't use the `row` and `col` iterators with `game` as they are from a different container. You can convert the iterators to numeric indexes by subtracting them from `begin`, e.g.: `other[row - other.game.begin()][col - row->begin()]`. This gets quite hard to read so you might be better off either using two separate iterators for each container or just using indexes for both containers.

The better solution is to let the standard library do the work for you:

```
std::copy(other.game.begin(), other.game.end(), game.begin());
```

There is no need to copy the elements of the inner vector one by one, assigning a vector to another one does the copying for you.